Returning the landing location of an object tracked using openCV from an irregular shaped region
I am using OpenCV to determine the landing location of an object using a camera from a top-down position. I have already gotten the code for the object tracking to work so that it not a problem. The issue I am having is with returning the location in which the object lands.
Because this is a work-related question I have made the background of the captured image white.
The target is a large (diameter) ring that is not very thick. What I am looking to do is figure out whether the object landed on the inner portion, center portion or outside portion of that ring.
The total landing area is a large ring with 3 zones (A,B,C) every five degrees for a total of 216 possible landing locations (image 1). The only thing the cameras sees is the ring. The section/zones and their sizes are decided in the code. By tracking the center point of the object contour I know the [x,y] coordinates (in the frame) for where the object lands. For my example the object lands in the 35 degree section, zone C. The problem I am having is that I don't know the best way to calculate and store all possible coordinates for each zone/section combination in such a way that when the object lands the program will output “The object landed in Section __ , zone __”.
Because each of the 216 locations is made up by some number of pixels each with their own [x,y] coordinates. My thought was that I would want to iterate over all of the 216 locations and store the possible coordinates that make up each location so that when I get the final position of the object I can compare it to my stored coordinates and return the location it landed in. For this I was considering a dictionary of dictionaries that stores all 72 sections, the three zones within each section, and all possible coordinate pairs within each zone. The reason I thought to use a dictionary was that I can easily return the keys (section and zone name) at the end.
To test whether I could accurately store all the pixels I have written code to color in the section using the equations for all points along the arc. It has not worked well as when I color those pixels I end up both repeating many pixels and also missing some (image 2). I tried revising the code to use Bresenham’s algorithm to try and fix this, but that did not work either (image 3).
A couple of notes that may be worth while:

This program is not a consumer facing project, it will be used for testing in-house so it needn’t be overly performant or efficient, but it is still better if it is. What is important is how accurate it is in returning the landing location.

The target and camera will always be fixed.

Once the object lands all tracking will stop  and then the landing location will be determined.


My questions are as follows:

Is what I described the correct approach to being able to return where the object lands (i.e. storing the pixel coordinates of defined zones in a dictionary of dictionaries to be compared against later)?

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to easily define 216 regions of interest that are irregular in shape (they are really just annulus sections). Are there any libraries I can import that would make this easier?

How can I accurately, and without repeats plot, or draw these sections pixel by pixel so that I can ensure I am not missing any points.


Here is sample of the code for plotting the pixels (using the non-Bresenham method):
step_size = 0.1
angle_start = 32.5
angle_end = angle_start + 398.2 + step_size
r_in_end = radius_inner + ring_thickness/2

r_out_in = r_out - ring_thickness
print(f'Inner radius (float): {r_out_in} | Inner radius (int): {int(r_out_in)}')
r_out_end = r_out
print(f'Outer radius (float): {r_out_end} | Inner radius (int): {int(r_out_end)}')
angle_value = np.arange(angle_start, angle_end, 0.2)
# print(angle_value)
# print(f'angle_value: {angle_value}')
# print(f'angle_value size: {len(angle_value)}')
section_length = r_out_end - r_out_in + 2

# Calculate the sizes of the outer for loop (height)
# calculate the size of the inner for loop (width)
# Initialize an empty array of the size needed (height X width) to fill
width = int((r_out_end + 1.5 - r_out_in - .5))
height = len(angle_value)
pixel_locations = np.zeros((width * height, 2), dtype=np.int32)

# Intitialize variables for storing points in the array and checking repeats in the array
index = 0
px_match = 0
prev_pt = (0, 0)

# Nest the loops to color pixels at every point along the arc
# for every step in the direction of the inner section radius to the outer section radius.
for r in range(int(r_out_in+.5), int(r_out_end+1.5)):

    for angle in angle_value:

        # Convert angle to radians and rename as theta for understandibility
        # Calculate the x and y positions of the pixel along the arc length
        theta = math.radians(angle)
        x = int(center_loc[0] + math.sin(theta) * r)
        y = int(center_loc[1] + math.cos(theta) * r)

        # Store the x and y coords in the empty array
        # Increment the index
        pixel_locations[index] = [x, y]
        index += 1

        # Error checking. We don't want a location to repeat
        if (x, y) == prev_pt:
            # print(f'The current position is:{x, y} | The previous position was: {prev_pt}')
            px_match += 1

        # Draw the new point on the image to give visual check that the function is working
        # cv2.circle(overlay, (x, y), radius=1, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=-1)
        overlay[y, x] = (255, 0, 0)
        
        # store the current location as the new previous for the next loop.
        prev_pt = (x, y)

# Print out number of repeats.
print(f'The number of overlapping pixels is: {px_match}')
Target_transparent = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, TargetImg_Resized, 1 - alpha, 0)


Why not transform x,y of the landing position to polar coordinates r, alpha with center at the x,y of central image pixel and then use simple < comparisons for r  and division for alpha instead of coping with images and pixels or dictionaries???

any approach involving a dictionary of a million coordinates is bad.

I agree and I was apprehensive about doing so. which is why I asked the question. The method of using polar coordinates was a far better solution.

if your areas can't be defined algebraically, just make a single-channel "picture" where each area has one "color" (integer label). look up any pixel's value, which is the area's identifying label, and that's it.
